# I got this error when i try to SignIN[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client - Flutter,GoogleSignIn

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

When i try to SignIn with Google [google_sign_in: ^6.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)

I got an error

```
[GSI_LOGGER-OAUTH2_CLIENT]: Popup timer stopped.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Trying to set gapi client token.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client library is not loaded in your page.
```

This is My Code :

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final authRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return AuthRepository(googleSignIn: GoogleSignIn());
});

class AuthRepository {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  AuthRepository({
    required GoogleSignIn googleSignIn,
  }) : _googleSignIn = googleSignIn;

  void googleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (user != null) {
        print(user.email);
        print(user.displayName);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Anybody encountered this problem and been able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are working with Flutter Web.
Have you done the [Web Implementation](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web#web-integration) for google_sign_in package?

Also, I found a great tutorial for your problem: https://codeontherocks.dev/blog/google-sign-in-flutter/

He wrote this about the error that you see:

> *This code will open the Google Sign In popup and allow the user to select their account. Once again, this process does not return an ID token so it is NOT RECOMMENDED. Further, you may see the following error logged in the console:*
>
> > `The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client library is not loaded in your page.`

> ***This message can be safely ignored although it should serve as a reminder that you will not have access to the user’s ID token.***

Please check the [example repository](https://github.com/CodeOTR/cotr-examples/tree/main/features/cotr_google_sign_in) as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function recently in my project and it work

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
     Future<String?> signInwithGoogle() async {
        try {
          final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
              await _googleSignIn.signIn();
          final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
              await googleSignInAccount!.authentication;
          final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
            idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
          );
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          print(e.message);
          throw e;
        }
      }
```

for more help follow this blog
https://petercoding.com/firebase/2021/05/24/using-google-sign-in-with-firebase-in-flutter/

if you understand Hindi/Urdu language follow this video for latest documentation and method
https://youtu.be/rt7B4tD67Gw

Comment: i'm not using firebase for google sign in